# I want to change texts which have same color without use any class/id etc. via JS

Tags: javascript

My design has many texts which have same color.I want to change their color depend click a button or a php variable.The texts havent ID also I cant find their classes because many different classes use same color.

So, shortest way is changing things which have same colors to solve my problem.

How can I do it by JS?

I want to change the colors by click a button for visitors also by php variable for admin panel.

Comment: Show us your code first.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 my question doesnt need any code.For example, I want to convert all red texts to yellow.

Comment: @Displayname you need to show the code that you want to change or add something, we can't repair/explain code that we didn't see, even when you explain it with words

Comment: Please don't use caps lock, it won't accelerate our answers. And, as asked before: show us your code in the question.

Comment: You need some kind of identifier to parse an elements content. Whether it be a class, ID or tag, something needs to be used to get the contents of the target you wish to manipulate. 

"So, shortest way is changing things which have same colors to solve my problem." 
Well css can only be accessed through an element selector type like tag, class, id you can not use css as a selector to find an element and in turn manipulate it.

Comment: I'm just reminding you the rules. If your question was clear, you wouldn't have those comments and you would probably already have an answer. StackOverflow users are here to help, but please remain calm.

Comment: @filipvkovic thanks your undersing.They talk about ID,Class or other things.So, do you know any way to select style without them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make up your mind on what elements really need to be changed. Does your color-change rule apply to literally all elements? - Just paragraphs, labels, or divs?

Upon making the decision, you can try something like this. I am assuming you are trying color change against all elements on the page.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
     if (node.style.color === 'red')
         node.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

`querySelectorAll` returns all elements that match the CSS selector passed as the first parameter. You can use wildcard character `*` to have it return every element on the screen.

But if you can possibly narrow down your rules and want it to be applied to `<label>` and `<p>` elements only, you can simply use it as follows

```js
document.querySelectorAll('label, p').forEach(function(node) {
     if (node.style.color === 'red')
         node.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the everything selector `*` to search all elements on the page and then write a conditional to check if the style.color is equal to the target...

```js
let everything = document.querySelectorAll('*');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  everything.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if(value.style.color === 'red') {
      console.log(value.textContent)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div style="color:red;">Lorem</div>
<p style="color:green;">ipsum</p>
<h1 style="color:blue;">Some Header</h1>
<p>dummy text</p>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: The OP mentioned there are no specific IDs or classes applied to the target elements.

Comment: @filipvkovic thanks your undersing.They talk about ID,Class or other things.So, do you know any way to select style without them?

Comment: You could use the * selector which select everything then add a conditional to check if the css style is set to a certain color...